# Impulsive and habitual hump in a GSD bitch, what could it be?

Tags: dogs, german-shepherd

**Background**

My 7 month old GSD (German Shepherd Dog) bitch seems to have developed what looks like a habitual and impulsive hump after cleaning herself.

Instantly or even during when cleaning her nether regions she starts to hump while sitting or laying (how ever she was cleaning herself). She isn’t jumping anything she’s just doing the motion of jumping on the spot. The only way to stop this is to distract her. Then she forgets it’s ever happened and goes about her business.

We have another GSD bitch who is already firmly established the hierarchy and herself as top dog and the 7 month old has accepted her place, no fights or grapple for power etc, they get along and cohabit very well and are practically inseparable.

She has not been spayed.

**Question**

What could the cause of the hump be?